# How to set arbitrary system.property from Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

If I run my app as `java jar -Dsomething=anything thejar.jar` then I have set a system property.

Can I do that via Spring Boot Configuration files or is my only option to defined a @Configuration class that reads a property and then sets the system property from that?

Answer (score 1):

Spring configuration is highly flexible and provides a hierarchy for resolving configuration properties. You can set properties using the [spring config server](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-configuration), environment variables (my preferred approach), system properties, application.yaml/propteries, etc. Check out the docs on [externalized configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config)

Say you wanted to set a property: `app.some.property=foo`. You can access this property from any bean using the value annotation:

```java
@Value("${app.some.property}")
private String someProperty;
```

And then you can set it at runtime using one of the approaches defined above:

**1. System Property**

```sh
java -jar -Dapp.some.property=foo thejar.jar
```

**2. Environment Variable**

```sh
export APP_SOME_PROPERTY="foo"
java -jar thejar.jar
```